# Why the value of variable D not change in this program?

Tags: c

I was do manual analysis to this code. Would wait that the value of variable D change to 1 after first call to F1 function, but conserve his value on 2.
Also i noticed that comment or not comment the `*Y--;` has no effect.

The output is:

```
8 9 5 2
5 9 5 2
15 13 4 2
5 13 4 2
```

Shouldn't variable D change your value to 1 after the first print?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int F1 (int, int *);
int A = 3;
int B = 7;
int C = 4;
int D = 2;

void main(void)
{
  A = F1 (C, &D);
  printf("\n %d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
  C = 3;
  C = F1(A, &C);
  printf("\n %d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
}

int F1 (int X, int *Y)
{
  int A;
  A = X * *Y;
  C++;
  B += *Y;
  printf ("\n %d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
  *Y--;
  return(C);
}
```

Comment: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Start with `-Wall` in GCC or `-Wmost` in Clang. Some compilers will warn you about the fact that `*Y--` had no useful effect and that `main` should be declared to return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Doesn’t this also result in undefined behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) issue.

```c
*Y--;
```

means

```c
*(Y--);
```

but you want

```c
(*Y)--;
```

Comment: Thank you for response.
So... *(Y--) means a direction beside *Y and  (*Y)-- means modify the value of the direction *Y? Certain?

Comment: `Y--` modifies the value of `Y`, which is a pointer. It changes where it points (which is nonsense here).

Comment: `*Y` deferences, which is to say gets what's the point points to, so `(*Y)--;` changes what Y points to.